# VisualVM on new 64-bit laptop with JDK7 can't connect to JMX agent

Tags: spring, weblogic, java-7, jmx, visualvm

I have a Spring app that runs fine on WebLogic 10.3.x on my old Win7-32bit laptop with JDK 1.6.  I can make a local connection to the app from VisualVM and view JMX properties and execute JMX methods.

I'm now setting up a new Win7-64bit laptop, with JDK 1.7 and WebLogic 12.1.2.0.  The app itself works almost without change (I had to add some package overrides in the weblogic-application.xml).

However, when I installed VisualVM (1.3.7) and installed all of the relevant plugins, I can connect to the process, but when I try to open the MBeans tab, it says:

```
Data not available because JMX connection to the JMX agent could not be established.
```

There's nothing useful in the VisualVM log.  I don't have quick access to the old laptop right now.  Is there perhaps a WebLogic command-line option I need in order to allow JMX connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this.  It simply requires setting the "com.sun.management.jmxremote" system property on the JVMs I want to target.  Curiously, I found an Oracle docs page that talks about this property, and it says it's not necessary to set this anymore.  My experience conflicts with that.

Comment: what value was set?

Comment: @NaiveCoder, you do not need to set a value. For running from the command-line, you would use: `java [...] -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote`